# Error when load json pretrained model in javascript in local web application

Tags: javascript, express, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

currently I am using TensorFlow to train a model in python and save it as model.json together with the BIN file in folder named models as shown as below. I want to do a web application that can load this pre-trained model for prediction. However, I encountered the error `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` I have googled the solutions and tried several ways, but the error still unable to be solved.

[image]

The model was trained in .py file and save into .json by using this line

```
tfjs.converters.save_keras_model(model, 'models')
```

For your information, I using node.js and ExpressJs in the application, therefore, the EJS file is used instead of HTML file.

**EJS file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@2.0.0/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style/digit.css">
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <p1>text here</p1>
    </main>   
    <script src="/js/digit-recognition.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In the **digit-recognition.js** file

```
let model;

async function loadModel() {
    console.log("model loading..");
    model = undefined;
    model = await tf.loadLayersModel("models/model.json");
    console.log("model loaded..");
}
loadModel();

$("#predict-button").click(async function () {

    let predictions = await model.predict(tensor).data();
    let results = Array.from(predictions);
    console.log(results);
});
```

I get the following error as displayed in the console:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

#### *Updated at 27 Nov 2020 1131am*

I have tried many suggested solutions online but it still not works, and the error I get is this now

```
GET http://localhost:3000/models/model.json 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a pathing issue. If you move the `models/` folder into the `js/` folder, the `digit-recognition.js` file should be able to find it.

Comment: Hi @Andy, thank you for the advice, I have tried as you suggest, to move the `models/` folder into `js/` folder, but the issue still persists. Now I got the latest error line instead of the previous one.

Comment: @YK try `model = await tf.loadLayersModel("js/models/model.json");`, this should be the proper path